# Focusing with Meade Audiostar

Tags: telescope, amateur-observing

I recently upgraded from a Meade ETX-RA to and ETX-EC and bought a used Audiostar controller. My EC came with a Meade autofocuser and one of the old (I think it’s 494) controllers that has the focus controls and the four lights on it. Is it possible to just plug the autofocuser AUX cord into the Audiostar and focus from that? I read the manual for the autofocuser and it seems like I should be able to. Just not sure which controls I am supposed to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that if you hold the mode key for about five seconds and have the 1244 focuser plugged into the mount then a screen will pop up that allows you to use the arrow keys on the top of the remote to adjust the focus. Once you are done focusing, you simply press mode to exit.